# JQuery html() vs. string

Tags: jquery

Consider the following code:

```
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
<li>Five</li>
</ul>

$('li').each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).html() == 'Three') 
        alert ('Three');
});
```

The code above will never hit the alert. I assume this has something to do with object vs. string values, but my brain is addeled from hours in front of the computer today. Can someone please clue me in as to how to make the comparison work? I tried using text() instead of html() as well, but that didn't seem to matter.

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/TADfk/).

Answer (score 1):

Your code works

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uGaeJ/)

Try to find JavaScript errors on somewhere else.